# How should we use the mipmap folders added with android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-drawable, mipmaps

I recently installed one more Android SDK to Android Studio, the SDK version 4.4 (API level 19), and after using it with my project, it added a set of `mipmap` folders in the project's `res` folder (`res/mipmap`).
I neither understand why, or how to use them.

I read another [question about it here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders).
The answer to it said that:

> The mipmap folders are for placing your app icons in only. Any other
>   drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable
>   folders as before.
>
> According to [this Google blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html):
>
> > It’s best practice to place your app icons in **mipmap-** folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions
> >     different from the device’s current density.

I still don't get the reason to this.
Why cant we just place the app icons in the `res/drawable` folders too?

Also, if only the app icon should be placed in the `mipmap` folders, how do I create other drawable assets and place them in the `drawable` folders with the Android Studio Image Asset wizard? (Accessed by right clicking in the project, selecting **New > Image Asset**)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mipmap drawables for icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why cant we just place the app icons in the res/drawable folders too?

Oh, you can. Google doesn't recommend it, that's all.

Quoting myself from Version 6.5 of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> While
>   drawable resources might be removed when packaging an APK, such as for the
>   Gradle for Android split system for making density-specific editions of an app,
>   mipmap resources are left alone, apparently

This is because launcher icons may be pulled from a higher-density bucket than the regular device density that is used for all other drawables. Putting them in `res/mipmap-*/` directories means that we won't inadvertently get rid of them as part of optimizing APK size.

(why they didn't handle this in a better way, I have no idea)

> how do I create other drawable assets and place them in the drawable folders with the Android Studio Image Asset wizard? (Accessed by right clicking in the project, selecting New > Image Asset)

The Image Asset wizard only puts launcher icons in `res/mipmap-*/` directories. If you choose the other icon types, they will go in `res/drawable-*/`. And, of course, the Image Asset wizard itself is optional.

Comment: Related: I like to support authors when our circles intersect. I just went on Amazon to buy a copy of your book [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://www.amazon.com/Busy-Coders-Guide-Android-Development/dp/0981678009). It seems a used copy is going for $267 USD. It looks like the new one is a bargain at $5,842.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't build one APK for each density. Is that something I should do when releasing it? And, if I don't build it for different densities, there is no real difference between the folders, right? Also, why I wondered about the *Image Asset* wizard was because it scales one image to fit all densities, instead of me having to resize them manually. Thanks!

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12: "Is that something I should do when releasing it? " -- not usually. It's mostly there for apps with a huge number of drawables, where there might be benefits to the user by stripping out ones that won't get used, based on the device's density. "And, if I don't build it for different densities, there is no real difference between the folders, right?" -- `mipmap` has fewer characters than `drawable`. :-) But, otherwise, yes, they should be equivalent. The fact that `mipmap` is ill-documented, though, means I'd lean towards `drawable`.

Comment: @jww: The book has been published as a digital-only title for a few years now. The print ones you are seeing on Amazon are seriously out of date, and are a fair bit more expensive than is my Warescription. Thanks for the interest!