# No resource found that matches the given name at icon/label

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I've a issue to generate a signed apk.

I have these errors

```
Error:(5, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [...] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cordova/[...]/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').

Error:(5, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [...] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cordova/[...]/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

Error:(6, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [...] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cordova/[...]/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/activity_name').
```

My strings.xml contains:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">@string/app_name</string>
    <string name="activity_name">@string/launcher_name</string>
</resources>
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml, the line with the @drawable/icon is:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

And you can see, i've the right file in the right folder...

[image]

How can I fix these errors?

**EDIT**

Now i've two error alert:

```
Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cordova/ABC/out/production/ABC/ABC.apk (No such file or directory)
```

and

```
Error: Cannot run program "/Users/John/Library/Android/sdk/tools/zipalign": error=13, Permission denied
```

Comment: bizarre clean, and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "@string" from string.xml and it will work fine.

android:label="@string/app_name"  ->  android:label="app_name"

@drawable/icon for ref : 
[mipmap drawables for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)