# Do I need to put my icons in both mipmap and drawable folders, if I am supporting older versions of android (before 4.3)?

Tags: android, android-drawable, mipmaps

There are many posts which suggest that you should use the mipmap folders for your app icons. This seems to have come in android 4.3

I intend to support older android devices (Android 2.3.3 and above).
I have:

```
minSDK: android-10
targetSDK: android-10
```

Does this mean I have to create drawable folders too ? What will happen if I put my app icons only in the mipmap folders and do not create drawable folders ? I only have a device with android 4.4.4 so I cannot test with earlier devices. What should I do ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders for reference

Comment: it is not a duplicate - that question applied for android 4.3 and above. If my target sdk is 2.3.3, then the api in question won't exist. So it is unclear what will happen. Hence my question.

Comment: use an emulator with gingerbread to test the behaviour.

Comment: Isn't there any documentation so I can verify the official behaviour ?

Comment: @John So have you been able to use it in 2.3.3 without any crashes ?

Comment: @Ahmed Can't remember what I did and switched projects - Best to test it with a device or the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) the `mipmap` folder are only to keep the app icons. The other images and icons used in application should be kept in associated `drawable` folders!

Comment: I am talking about only app icons, but the mipmaps api was introduced in android 4.3. Since I am targeting devices before 4.3 (android 2.3.3>=), this api won't exist! :) That's why I wan't to know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

App icon(logo) should only be in mipmap folder. Placing the different size if images in the mipmap folder will show icons in every android phone. Drawble folder contain images which is used inside the app.
**Short**
You don't need to put app icon in drawable if you already have it in mipmap folder.

Comment: But what about pre android 4.3 ? The google documentation says something about this being introduced in 4.3, so what happens to earlier os versions ?

Comment: Although it was introduced in 4.3. It works fine on previous versions too.
Infact I am using it in my current project.