# Design your app for tablets

Tags: android

I need help designing an app for tablets.

My app was uploaded into Play Store contains everything related to tablet screen size, such as:

layout folder:

- activity_main.xml
- activity_main.xml(w600dp)
- activity_main.xml(w720dp)

mipmap folder:

- image.png(hdpi)
- image.png(mdpi)
- image.png(xxdpi)

Manifest.xml I also put

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But the Optimization Tip still alerts me as follows:

> Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.

Comment: do you have drawable folders, thats probably why its alerting you, usually its there you put your png icons etc for different screen sizes

Comment: Hi Tasos, Yes, I have drawable but all image asset I stored in mipmap folder. It's wrong that I stored image asset in mipmap?

Comment: reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons  mipmap folders should only have the launcher icons so  move all  icons from there in their respected drawable folders and change @mipmap/ .. to @drawable/.. but keep the launcher one in the mipmap's folder

Comment: Hi Tasos Aug, Thanks you so much for your help :)
Now I can make my app support to all screen size by adding image to drawable folder (h, x, xx, xxx) and modifies Manifest file :)