# Cannot insert image using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, imagebutton

Why I cannot insert the image by using this method? Does it has another way so that  `ca` can be inserted to `mipmap`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't beacuse you are in 'Android' view type. Change to 'Project' view in top-left selector. Actually, `ic_drawer.png` is not a directory, but a set of 4 directories. One per image dimension.

[image]

You should put your images in drawables. Mipmap is only recommended for icons.

Comment: I want to use imageButton...where should I put the image?

Comment: @seng tony Put image in drawables not in Mipmap folder. Android recommends AppIcon to be put in MipMap folder

Comment: @silwar but before this, I insert picture for the navigation drawer, it works

Comment: Please check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons) post? this will provide you better idea about mipmap