# Device shows default droid icon instead of app launcher icon

Tags: android

I changed the launcher icon file and it's name(from ic_logo to ic_launcher) and made respective changes in the Manifest.

Some devices(Moto-G, Moto Razor) which updated the app since then see the default droid icon instead of the actual ic_launcher icon.
The same devices would see the proper launcher icon if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled, instead of just updating.

It shouldn't be a problem with the folders the icon is placed in. Because it works fine on most of the devices and after uninstall and reinstall on the above mentioned devices. Just for reference:

[image]

Anything I can do to make it work in the next update(without uninstalling)?

Comment: It's just mobile cache. Try to use a new theme on mobile.

Comment: its their default launcher cache implementation

Comment: have you replaced all drawable launcher icon with your custom icon

Comment: in Android Studio launcher icon is in side @mipmap folder so replace those images with your.

Comment: you just use mipmap instead of drawble in android studio.

Comment: just check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690662/2326640, i search for  days an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project once and then try

Answer (score 0):

For Application Icon, try to put them in `@mipmap` directory. That's what Google recommends and sometimes stupid bugs happen when you don't follow the guidelines.

Read 
[mipmap drawables for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)