# Android Studio app icon

Tags: android, android-studio

(I've updated the post)

Here's how I have my proyect:

Manifest:

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Mipmap:
Created by New > Image Asset
I selected Launcher Icons (Adaptative and Legacy)

[Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2tG7.png)

Also, when I open any of them I see the icon I want:

[Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5l2b.png)

Now, the launcher icon works just fine:

[Launcher Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXDLP.png)

The problem I'm having is that it does not want to update the icon that is displayed when I'm going to select another app.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHoZZ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update both property of application tag in manifest file.

```
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" <-- Change this one
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" //<-- and this one
```

or you can remove

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" //<-- and this one
```

ensure you have place all mipmap/drawable in correct place and for all dpi.

reach me if you have still problems.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app folder and go under drawable. Right Click -> New -> Image Asset.

From there you can select what kind of image you want for the different options given.

Comment: If I set the icon attribute it changes the launcher, but when I change the roundIcon it does nothing, even if I set it to the same as icon.

Comment: I tried deleting the icons and creating them again, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a common cache issue. Sometimes when you run the app from Android studio or in debug mode you will have this droid icon.

When you stop and don't reinstall the app, droid icon is still there for futures launches... You have to **clear the cache** to get back your icon.

I search a correct answer for days because this is very stange and still not fixed...

Hope this will help !