# Android Setting Icon To Notification Builder

Tags: android

I am setting the required drawable to Notification.Builder but it says cannot resolve. I have tried to use the `ic_launcher` which would not work so I added my own `wuno_launcher` and that will not work either.

```
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("New Affirmation");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wuno_launcher); // error here cannot resolve symbol
        return builder.build();
}
```

But I am sure I have the icon added as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You should only place `ic_launcher`icons in the `mipmap` folder. Move any other drawables to a `drawable` folder (e.g. `drawable-xhdpi`)

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use mipmap folder image so you have use mipmap instead of drawable. Do something like this

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.wuno_launcher)
```

Comment: Thanks man. So that was why the ic_launcher would not work. So For my custom image I would drop in drawable. But the ic_luancher just use your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google documentation, `mipmap` icons are used only for launcher icon which is also known as app_icon. Mipmap icons are reffered by using [R.mipmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.mipmap.html)

[Here is a good explanation of the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)