# About Android Image Scaling

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-resources, mipmaps

I needed to add an image into my relative layout. I found a picture with a big enough resolution (1129x1489). Then I flowed these steps to input the image.

1. Right click on res, new **Image Asset**
2. Select **Launcher Icons** (because I wanted my image to have colour)
3. On **Asset Type** choose **Image**
4. Choose image path
5. Give it a name and finish

The image would then be saved under mipmap like so

[image]

However, when added to the layout it was very small and became blurry when stretched (when set to either `match_parent` or `fill_parent`).

[image]

The code used :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/big"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Then I decided to just copy and paste the image into the **drawable** folder and simply changing the code to `android:src="@drawable/big"`. Then the android emulator displayed the image properly.

[image]

[image]

My question is, what is the proper way of inserting an image like this and why did it seem like the proper image size (xhdpi) was not being chosen from the **mipmap** folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your res folder, create five folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi. Now, drop the appropriate image into each of the folders and in your code, use it as "@drawable/big" and it'll show up correctly.

Comment: Yes but why doesn't this work with **mipmap**? All of the sizes are already there. As shown in my picture.

Comment: Mipmaps are only for app launch icons and such. This is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066445/3674262 For images used inside the app, drawable folders are appropriate.