# Android use mipmap folder instead of drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-mipmap

I did read a lot of info about `mipmap` and `drawable` folders.

Still I can't understand - what bad thing would happen, if I use **mipmap folder only for all my images**?

**Upd.** Please **READ** the question, I know, that mipmap folder is for app icons.
The question is why I can't use it for other resources?

**Upd2.** If you put minus to this question, please consider posting comment with explanation.

Comment: nothing bad would happen. its all about density and resolution. mipmap is best for image if sizing matter for difference devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mipmap drawables for icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)

Comment: The answer to your question can be found reading the answers to the linked "duplicate": quote from the answer by [Kazuaki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365962/5015207): "drawables may be stripped out as part of dp-specific resource optimisation. Mipmaps will not be stripped" So if you put everything in the mipmap folders you will end up needing more space for your app than necessary.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only.

```
It's best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders 
(not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions
different from the device's current density.
```

Comment: About app icons - ok. But read my question - what bad would happen, if I put ALL images into mipmap folder?