# Android - No launcher icon after installing apk

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

I know that this question has been asked many times, but the old answers don't resolve my issue, maybe something has changed.
Why there is no launcher icon after installing the apk?

This is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.xxx.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xx.xx.MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xx.xx.Configuration"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xx.xx.xx.xx"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What is the problem? Please Guide.

Comment: Check this
Run ==> Edit Configuration ==> Launch Option ==> xx.xx.xx.xx.MyActivity

Comment: make sure to clear the cache of app and install app again.

Comment: Launcher icon should be present in the mipmap folder not in drawable folder.Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons

Answer (score 0):

App icon should be in `minmap` like this

- minmap-mdpi/ic_launcher
- minmap-hdpi/ic_launcher
- minmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher
- minmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher
- minmap-xxxdpi/ic_launcher

not in `Drawable`, so please change it. and also check icon size.

try this link to make app icon
https://makeappicon.com/

Comment: It should be in minmap folders but it works in drawable as well.

Comment: it will work, but its better to use minmap and please check size of icon

Comment: I create the icons with makeappicon.com, create the folders and set android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher", but doesn't work

Comment: `android:icon="@minmap/ic_launcher"` apply this only to application, remove else where, Try it and let me know