# Blurry Launcher Icons

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, blurry

I am trying to add a launcher icon to my Android application, but something seems wrong with resolution whan app is installed. The device I'm working with has an XHDPI screen, so I am testing with a 96x96 (px) image. I used the Image Asset in Android Studio to generate a default icon:

[image: XHDPI (96x96) icon]

This is the result in my device:
[image]

You can notice that the image is a bit blurry, as it has been resized. It happens with every icon I make. What is happening? I am using MIUI, altough it doesn't appears to affect to the other icons.

EDIT: My launcher icon is inside the mipmap folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android application icon goes blurry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271491/android-application-icon-goes-blurry)

Comment: I suppose the generated icons are stored in the drawable folder rather than the mipmap one. You should switch to the latter one if that's the case.

Comment: I have edited my post. The icon is already stored in the mipmap folder.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Your file from mipmap-anydp-v26 folder..
it might work for you like me

Answer (score 0):

Place your launcher icons in the mipmap folders instead of drawable. Some phones scale launcher icons up. Putting you launch icons in mipmap folders will have the phone use a large resolution icon if needed.

[mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

Comment: My launcher icon is in the mipmap folder (which is one of the solutions proposed in the other post suggested as duplicated), so I don't think this is the problem... By the way, I created a default project with Android Studio and extracted the icon (in the mipmap folder, yes). If I include it in my app, everything works fine, but if I modify the PNG files beyond the icon padding, I get blurry icon again. Very weird...

Answer (score -2):

If it is a PNG file try using a vector image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912428/android-vector-drawable-for-launcher-icon-and-other-images-on-android-n